# Stop propagation of a div inside a div

Tags: vuejs2, click, vuetify.js, stoppropagation

I have a card inside another clickable card. In my case, a carousel inside a card. 
In a usual situation, I know I have to use `@click.stop` to prevent opening the parent card from opening when I click something clickable inside it.... but in my case, I'm having a [carousel](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/carousels/) which do not have a click event, hence, I'm unable to use stop event on it. 
 So what happens is when I click the next arrow of the carousel, the parent card pops up too. 

 Any idea how do I use `stop event handling` on something that do not have click event?

```
________________
|            <-|---- Master Card
| ------------ |
| |       <--|-|---- Carousel
| |__________| |
|              |
|              |
|______________|
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr:**

In Vue, if you want to stop the native click events, you have to use the `native` event modifier:

```
<carousel @click.native.stop />
```

or

```
<carousel @click.native.stop="yourMethod" />
```

Internally, the `.stop` modifier calls `.stopPropagation()` on the native `click` event, besides running `yourMethod` with the click `event` as param (when `yourMethod` is specified).

`$emit()`-ted `click` events (i.e: `$emit('click', payload)` don't need stopping, as they are not propagating by default.

---

**complete answer:** (regardless of Vue)

Any HTML element has an `onclick` event.

Therefore,

```
document.querySelector('.your-selector').onclick = function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
}
```

will stop the `click` event's propagation (assuming `document.querySelector('.your-selector')` does select your carousel - note `querySelector` only returns the first element matching the selector).

If you want to do this on multiple elements matching the same selector, you'll need to use `querySelectorAll` and iterate through each element. Example:

```
 [...document.querySelectorAll('.your-selector')].forEach(el => {
   el.onclick = function(e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
   }
 });
```

---

There are less verbose ways of doing it using frameworks, such as jQuery:

```
$('.your-selector').on('click', e => { e.stopPropagation(); })
```

... which does it on the entire collection returned by `$('.your-selector')`, out of the box.

Comment: What I meant is that Vuetify's carousel does not have a click props or event on it's `<` and `>` (next and previous button).

Comment: How about you create a [mcve] with what you've done so far? And I'll edit it to `preventDefault` on any carousel click. Deal?